# How to retrieve data from relational column from Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am developing Android application and for this I have Created two classes at Parse. Both classes are custom.

- One class's name is "Admission" and
- Another class's name is "Exam".

**Admission class** has three columns:

```
 1. Name  
 2. Description 
 3. and Results.
```

**Exam class** has two columns:

```
 1. Result 
 2. Name
```

I have taken Results column of Admission relation type. This column is targeted to Exam class.

I want to retrieve data from Results column. How do I do this?
Please explain how could I use relation in Parse, I have gone through Parse docs, but it is not helpful .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can inline the array of ''Admission.Results' in a query by appending "?include=Results" as parms to the end of the query's url

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to get ParseRelation object from your Admission class Object for your relational column like this

> ParseRelation resultRelation=admissionObject.getRelation("Results");

then call `getQuery()` on this resultRelation object like this

> ParseQuery query=resultRelation.getQuery();

Now set condition in this query object to retrieve your Result column data.

Comment: please help me with storing and retrieving relation from a local datastore instead of making a network call.

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada , you can say query.fromLocalDatastore(); and make sure you have Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this); in Application class just before Parse.initialize(this);